# When can a bowler start his run up?

Tags: rules, cricket

In cricket, can a bowler start his run-up to the delivery before the batsman takes his stance?

Comment: https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/18519/responsibility-of-the-batsman-to-be-ready-for-the-bowler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, it is a batter's responsibility to be in stance when the bowler starts his run up. If not, he will get a warning, and potentially a penalty.

See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_and_unfair_play#Time_wasting) on fair play:

> In normal circumstances the striker should always be ready to take
>   strike when the bowler is ready to start his run up. If he wastes
>   time, in the first instance the batsman is warned by the umpire. That
>   warning applies to the batting team as a whole and each incoming
>   batsman is informed of that warning. If there is further time wasting
>   by any batsman in that innings, the umpires award the fielding side 5
>   runs and inform the Governing Body so it may consider further
>   disciplinary action.